# Try to have a UIImage in a MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, uiimage, mkannotation

I try to have a UIImage in a MKAnnotation:

```
UIView *leftCAV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
    leftCAV.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]];
pin.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftCAV;
```

The code is run, but I don't have a transparent background

See that:

http://img19.imageshack.us/f/1234wr.png/

Have an idea?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
leftCAV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

?

I'll assume your image is 32x32. Does it have a transparent background? (I could not tell if what I was looking at at the link you provided was what you intended. There's too much going on on that site! :-)

Comment: it is an *.png transparent in 32*32. I have try your solution but it's not good. I think there is a bug with my uicolor allocation

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not just using an imageView?

```
UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Location.png"]];
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = iconView;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this `leftCAV.opaque=NO;`.